# How user can see their own data when they are logged in using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a mobile app where i use Firebase as my backend-as-a-service. I am using Firebase SDK Authentication and Cloud Firestore from Firebase.

My problem is that i want a user to only see their own data when they are logged in. I saw that you could use your user-id in your database collection and then the document ID would be the user-id.

This is how far my code looks but it gives me error about that db.collection is not a function:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { auth, db } from '../../firebase/firebase'
import { collection, doc} from 'firebase/firestore';

export default function CreateUserComponent() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState('');
  const [lastname, setLastname] = useState('');
  const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users");


  const handleSignUp = () => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(userCredentials => {
        userCredentials.user;
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message))
  };

  const createUserData = async () => {
    auth
      .onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        usersCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).set({
          email: email,
          username: username,
          firstname: firstname,
          lastname: lastname,
          password: password
        })

      });
  }


  const handleSignUpAndPostData = () => {
    handleSignUp();
    createUserData();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.container}>CreateUserComponent: Welcome to your 
         registration</Text>
      </View>
     <View>
          <Text>E-mail:</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Enter your email" value={email} 
           onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}></TextInput>
          <Text>Username:</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Enter your username" value= 
           {username} onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)}></TextInput>
          <Text>Firstname:</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Enter your firstname" value= 
           {firstname} onChangeText={text => setFirstname(text)}></TextInput>
          <Text>Lastname:</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Enter your lastname" value= 
           {lastname} onChangeText={text => setLastname(text)} ></TextInput>
          <Text>Password:</Text>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} secureTextEntry placeholder="Enter your 
           password" value={password} onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}> 
          </TextInput>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Button onPress={handleSignUpAndPostData} title= "Continue"/>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
       fontSize: 16,
       fontWeight: 'bold',
       color: 'dodgerblue',
       marginTop: 100,
       padding: 20
    },
    view: {
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    input: {
       borderWidth: 1,
       borderColor: '#777',
       padding: 8,
       margin: 10,
       width: 200,
       backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    button: {
       marginTop: 20,
       width: "30%",
  }
})
```

This is the error messages it gives me:
[usersCollectionRef.doc is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKGVa.png)
[UsersCollectionRef.doc(user.uid)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnSp5.png)

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the code you're showing?  Which line?  What else have you done to debug this?

Comment: I know where the problem is because of some console.log i made. It is my usersCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).set({}) that is failing because it does not show the console log after that line, but the console.log works between onAuthStateChanged and usersCollectionRef.

Comment: Your question says the error is "db.collection is not a function" but that's not shown in the code snippet you shared. How do you know `usersCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).set({})` is failing without a callback handler attached? What error do you get in the console? I assume `usersCollectionRef.doc(user.uid).set({})` fails because `user.uid` is still `undefined` at the time of execution.

Comment: Please note that `.then(userCredentials => { userCredentials.user; })` makes no sense in your snippet.

Comment: You have that error because you're mixing two different syntax. What Firestore Web Version are you using? Is it v8 or v9?

Comment: Are you using the namespaced version of Firebase? v8 or v9?

Comment: This line right here:   `const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users");` uses v9.
and the line on `set()` uses v8. so which are you using?

Comment: The .then(userCredentials => { userCredentials.user} was because i needed that for console.log, sorry about that, but i am using v9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshots you have attached, the `doc` method does not exist on `usersCollectionRef` which is correct if you're using the modularized Firebase version.

Start [here in the Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). For your use case, it will look like this:

```js
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// ...

setDoc(doc(db, `users/${user.uid}`), { 
  // your data you want to write to Firestore
});
```

Comment: Just to be sure before i dig into the documentation, are there a way i can check if im using firebase v8 or v9? I tried firebase tools --version and firebase --version but it says the term firebase is not recognized from the VS Code terminal

Comment: Pro tip: check the documentation _before_ you ask questions. You can find the version of Firebase in your `package.json` if you have one - not sure how it works for React Native.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

Hey -

1. Yes, using the user's `uid` from firebase authentication is a great system
2. A best practice to query a user's documents is to add the user's `uid` as a field on their documents. That means adding a `uid` property on your Users collection that matches the users auth().currentUser.uid.

#### Some rationale and example

This allows you to easily query only the documents for a specific user.

For example, let's say you have a note-taking app with a "Users" collection for user profiles and a "Notes" collection to store each note in it's own document.

Each document in the "Users" collection would have a `uid` property, and each document in the "Notes" collection would also have a `uid` property.

To query the user's profile you query for `Users.where("uid", ===, auth().currentUser.uid).limit(1)`

To query all of this user's notes, you would do `Notes.where("uid", ===, auth().currentUser.uid)`.

Additionally, if you had folders for notes in the app, you would add a folderId to each note.

Firestore was optimized for very large and flat document collections. You just need to make sure you are adding all of the proper ids to documents so that you can properly query them.